# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS installation doesn't recognise exisiting Centos OS

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, boot-partition

I already have CentOS 9 installed on my ThinkCentre m93. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 alongside this OS and came across a warning during the installation process. It warns me that there isn't an existing OS on the drive. I've attached screenshots of the message as well as other commands during installation and commands from CentOS.

What do I need to do to get Ubuntu installed alongside CentOS?

Here are a few commands from CentOS:

```
centos_adm[@]10:38:14[~]$ lsblk 
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2        8:2    0 118.2G  0 part 
  ├─cs-root 253:0    0    70G  0 lvm  /
  ├─cs-swap 253:1    0   7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─cs-home 253:2    0  40.5G  0 lvm  /home
centos_adm[@]10:38:31[~]$
centos_adm[@]10:38:32[~]$
centos_adm[@]10:38:32[~]$ df -hl
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs             4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs                3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                1.5G  9.5M  1.5G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/cs-root   70G  7.0G   63G  10% /
/dev/sda1           1014M  295M  720M  30% /boot
/dev/mapper/cs-home   41G  6.4G   35G  16% /home
tmpfs                758M  116K  758M   1% /run/user/1000
```

CentOS disk utility:

[image]

Screenshots that were taken during the Ubuntu 22.04 installation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: apologies, it is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: When you installed CentOS, did you encrypt the disk?

Comment: @Will i don't think i did, but i ran this command: `centos_adm[@]10:29:20[~]$ sudo blkid /dev/sda*
/dev/sda: PTUUID="3f089afd" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/sda1: UUID="3dc5f98c-cff7-4a90-833d-bdf7cc435470" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="3f089afd-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="CNCt39-hd3F-9tMd-nGl8-lvCa-uUl1-WAxTED" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="3f089afd-02"
`